# Obtain Family and Order of a TimeSeriesModel

Tags: time-series

Example from the docs:

```
data = RandomFunction[ARMAProcess[{.1}, {.2}, 1], {1, 10^4}];
mod = TimeSeriesModelFit[data]
```

[image]

How can I extract from it the `Family` and `Order`? I need to obtain something like

> ARMA[{1,1}]

Note: I don't want `Normal[mod]`.

Comment: Well you can extract the family with `mod["ModelFamily"]`. Not sure about Order.

Comment: What you're looking for seems to be embedded in `mod["CandidateSelectionTable"]`, not sure how to pull that out though.

Comment: What does `mod["Methods"]` or `mod["Properties"]` return for you?

Comment: @J.M.iscomputer-less [Nothing useful](https://imgur.com/a/UNPFF09)

Comment: Then can you please try evaluating `mod["ModelString"]` or `mod["Process"]`?

Comment: @J.M.iscomputer-less Yes! You can post `mod["ModelString"]` as an answer.

Comment: I would ask that you post an answer yourself, since you did the evaluation to check. :) (I was only going by memory here.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per [J. M.'s comment](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/183783/obtain-family-and-order-of-a-timeseriesmodel?noredirect=1#comment479497_183783):

```
mod["ModelString"]
```

> "TimeSeriesModel[ARMA,{1, 1}]"

returns a string. To get the crucial bits:

```
#[[1]][#[[2]]] &@ToExpression[mod["ModelString"]]
```

> ARMA[{1, 1}]

Comment: (+1)  can also use  `Compose @@ ToExpression[mod["ModelString"]]` .